# gnome default file manager for intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gnome, file-manager

This is just a little problem, but very annoying. When I right click on a file in an intellij ide and want to view it in the file manager the application Anjuta is launched.

System is Arch Linux with recent updates, gnome 3.20.

When I uninstall Anjuta the behavior is as expected, but I don't want to uninstall it.

So, does anyone knows where to set the default file manager for an intellij ide.

Best Regards!!